# PHP - NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php

I have a PHP script:

```
<?php

  $etf = str_replace('/', '-', $_GET["f"]);
  $ett = str_replace('/', '-', $_GET["t"]);

  echo $etf;
  echo "<br />";
  echo $ett;

  $begin = new DateTime( $etf );
  $end = new DateTime( $ett );
  $end->modify('+1 day');

  $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
  $period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

?>
```

That when accessed like so:

http://www.website.co.uk/test.php?f=27/07/2015&t=01/08/2015

Produces this result:

```
27-07-2015
01-08-2015
```

With this error:

```
NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error
```

The idea is to loop through each day within the range but why do I get a 500 internal server error?

Thanks

Comment: Check your error log

Comment: Thanks!! Turns out it required a timezone to be set: `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');`

Comment: @Lee you should answer your own question by telling how you found the error and what you did to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

As user PeeHaa suggested I had a look in the error log and found that the server required a timezone to be set:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
```

This fixed my problem